# does uncorrelatedness of even powers of multivariate Gaussian imply independence?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X=(X_1,X_2, \dots X_n)$ be a centered multivariate Gaussian vector. If

$$
\operatorname{E} \left( X_1^{2\alpha} X_2^{2\alpha} \dots X_n^{2\alpha} \right)
=
\operatorname{E} \left( X_1^{2\alpha} \right) \operatorname{E} \left( X_2^{2\alpha} \right) \dots \operatorname{E} \left( X_n^{2\alpha} \right)
$$
for some positive integer $\alpha$, does it necessarily follow that all components of $X$ are independent, i.e. that the covariance matrix is diagonal?

It is conjectured that the left hand side is always larger than or equal to the right hand side and that equality holds precisely in the case of independence. I'm trying to understand whether this second assertion about equality is nontrivial as well or just some corollary which can also be shown directly.

The conjecture is known to be true if $\alpha=1$ or if $n=2$ (with $\alpha$ an arbitrary positive integer), so in these cases my question is answered affirmatively. I'm interested in the general case.

Thanks in advance!